# Creating a spreadsheet with drop downs that work off of each other

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 different planting suppliers.  Each supplier has prices for each of my areas (States).  Normally, I’ve used the tab called Combined Bids and done the arithmetic on my own.
[Combined Bids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peDAV.jpg)

I’d like to make something where I can choose from dropdowns and it give me the price based on the dropdowns I choose.
For instance, if I chose Alabama, Reforestation Specialists, Loblolly, 8x10, and Hoedad on the “Interface” tab it would return $52.06.
["Interface"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U5CZ.jpg)
[Lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owIHY.jpg)
I’ve tried using IF statements in the data validation, but I never seem to get it correct.  Thought about a Lookup table but I don’t know.
How would you do it?  Any information or help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much.  I'd be happy to share the spreadsheet as well.  I didn't see a place to upload it.  Again thanks!

Comment: Please edit your post to show only the necessary information and not the full story

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This](https://trumpexcel.com/dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/) is something you might want to look into.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a drop down list using [Data Validation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b)

and then get the value using the [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/he-il/office/vlookup-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%94-vlookup-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) function